# Exclude hidden files when searching with Unix/Linux find?

Tags: linux, command-line, unix, find

What options do I need to use with [`find`](//wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)) to exclude hidden files?

Comment: **Aside:** the reason there isn't some special support for this task is that the *only* thing special about files named with a leading '.' is that there are not listed by `ls` unless specifically requested: they are completely ordinary files in every respect, its just that `ls` lets you ignore them by default.

Comment: Question: do you want to hide something like `.hidden/visible.txt`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found this [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/how-to-tell-find-to-not-search-inside-hidden-folders-208169/):

```
find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f -name "whatever"
```

Comment: Why not just `\( ! -name '.*' \)`?

Comment: @grawity I just found that, I don't know entirely how it works.  Would yours not only hide hidden files, but hidden directories and all their sub-content and hidden files in subfolders?

Comment: No, it wouldn't :/ But `\( ! -path '*/.*' \)` would.

Comment: @grawity Ya, I guess I made an assumption about what the OP wanted... Your -name solution is probably the closest to what they were asking for.

Comment: @grawity&Dan: Isn't it \( !-path '^.*' \) ?? your solutions will ignore any file that has a '.' anywhere in the file name like a.exe, b.out etc....

Comment: @AnandJeyahar Nope, those are file "globs", not regular expressions; they always have to match from the start to the end of the filename / path

Comment: Could anyone explain the regex-syntax, please? (especially after the first asterisk)

Comment: The regex `'.*/\..*'` means: match anything (`.*`) until {one slash (`/`) and one dot (`\.`) after} and then anything (`.*`). Or, shorter: anything that has a sequence of one slash and a dot (`/\.`) inside. The pattern (not a regex) used in path (`'*/.*'`) is the same: match anything that contains a (`/.`), and here the dot is literal as this is a pattern, not a regex.

Answer (score 26):

It seems negation glob pattern is not well known. So you can use:

```
find . -name "[!.]*"
```

Comment: note that this will still find non-hidden files in hidden directories, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 14):

This doesn't answer your question, but for the task of finding non-hidden files I like to let find find all the files then filter with grep.

```
find . -type f | grep -v '/\.'
```

Similar to your approach but perhaps a bit simpler.

Comment: This was the only one of the one liners that worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

Try the following `find` usage:

```
find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*'
```

Which would ignore all the hidden files (files and directories starting with a dot).

Answer (score 3):

#### [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd)

Use `fd`, a simple, much faster and user-friendly alternative to `find`. By default, it:

- Ignores hidden directories and files, by default.
- Ignores patterns from your `.gitignore`, by default.

Check the [Benchmark analysis](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd#benchmark).

Answer (score 2):

If you aims is to `find` and `grep`, [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) does exclude hidden files by default, e.g.

```
rg --files
```

> `--files` Print each file that would be searched without actually performing the search.

Answer (score 2):

To find hidden files:

```
find -name '[.]*'
```

To find visible files:

```
find -name '[!.]*'
```

It is that simple.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a script called `findnh` which I believe handles certain edge cases better than the answers to this question that I've been able to find on the web.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a paths

while [ $# -ne 0 ]; do
  case "$1" in -*) break ;; esac
  paths+=("$1")
  shift
done

find "${paths[@]}" \( -name . -o -name .. -o \! \( -name '.*' -prune \) \) "$@"
```

For example, you can find non-hidden files and directories inside of an explicitly-specified hidden directory with a command like `findnh ~/.hiddendir/`, which will show `~/.hiddendir/file` but not `~/.hiddendir/.superhiddenfile`.

Comment: Nice bit of coding. Except, when I try `findnh ~/.hiddendir/`, I get nothing. Other than that, how is this different from `! -path '*/.*'` and `find … | grep -v '/\.'`?